# UPDATE column using COUNT

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want the parameter 'HoursPerWeek' to Equal the number of pupils with a specific Teachers ID.
I'm really lost on how to go about this.

```
CREATE PROC spUpdateTeachingHoursAndWages
AS
update Payments.HoursPerWeek
set HoursPerWeek = (select COUNT(PupilDetails.Teacher_ID)
FROM Assignment.dbo.Payments JOIN Assignment.dbo.PupilDetails 
ON Payments.ID = PupilDetails.Teacher_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try to update `HourPerWeek` and `with a specific Teachers ID`, you should add a parameter to your stored procedure just to indicate the Teacher_ID.

NOTE: I've used a `int` value change it according your table schema.

```
CREATE PROC spUpdateTeachingHoursAndWages (@Teacher_ID int)
AS
    UPDATE Payments
    SET    HoursPerWeek = (SELECT COUNT(PupilDetails.Teacher_ID)
                           FROM   Assignment.dbo.Payments 
                           JOIN   Assignment.dbo.PupilDetails 
                           ON     Payments.ID = PupilDetails.Teacher_ID
                           WHERE  Payments.ID = @Teacher_id)
    WHERE Payments.ID = @Teacher_ID
```

Comment: Thanks you, however I'm getting an `invalid object  name` error for HoursPerWeek. Will try to see whats causing the conflict.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought Payments was schema name, but it its the table name, remove .HoursPerWeek

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually figured it out :)  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @McNets is correct, but there can be modifications:

Better use [table aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx) and there is no need for sub-query:

```
CREATE PROC spUpdateTeachingHoursAndWages --(@Teacher_ID int)
AS
UPDATE p
SET HoursPerWeek = COUNT(pd.Teacher_ID)
FROM Assignment.dbo.Payments p
INNER JOIN Assignment.dbo.PupilDetails pd
    ON p.ID = pd.Teacher_ID
--WHERE p.ID = @Teacher_ID
--Uncomment this, if you need to change HoursPerWeek for some special teacher
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using a specific `Teacher_ID` parameter:

Correlated subquery version:

```
create proc spUpdateTeachingHoursAndWages as
begin;
set nocount, xact_abort on;
  update p 
  set HoursPerWeek = (
      select count(*)
      from Assignment.dbo.PupilDetails pd
      where pd.Teacher_id = p.id
      )
  from Assignment.dbo.Payments p;
end;
go
```

`inner join` version:

```
create proc spUpdateTeachingHoursAndWages as
begin;
set nocount, xact_abort on;
  update p 
  set HoursPerWeek = pd.HoursPerWeek
  from Assignment.dbo.Payments p
    inner join (
      select 
          pd.id
        , HoursPerWeek = count(*) 
      from Assignment.dbo.PupilDetails pd
      group by pd.id
      ) pd
      on p.id = pd.Teacher_id;
end;
go
```

[**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) version:

```
create proc spUpdateTeachingHoursAndWages as
begin;
set nocount, xact_abort on;
  update p 
  set HoursPerWeek = pd.HoursPerWeek
  from Assignment.dbo.Payments p
    cross apply(
      select HoursPerWeek = count(*) 
      from Assignment.dbo.PupilDetails pd
      where p.id = pd.Teacher_id;
      ) pd
end;
go
```

Note: [Why you should always include `set xact_abort, nocount on;` - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpXACT_ABORT)